# Memory Consumption of a C++/OpenGL program

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, memory

I've an application running on Windows using OpenGL and i'm focusing on memory usage. Currently i've 4 different values during runtime and i'm asking myself what is really going on in application/windows.

1. In Visual Studio 2015 diagnostic tool 62MB
2. Taskmanager 52MB
3. Visual Studio Memory profiler Heap Memory 17MB
4. GetProcessMemoryInfo.WorkingSetSize 78MB

Under Linux i've got in top RES 36MB....

It's quite confusing! Which memory is included 1, 2 and 4? Is GPU memory included?
Is there any way to divide memory consumption in application simple new/delete, GPU memory, Windows (window itself and other handles), OpenGL etc.?

Comment: GPU memory is not included in all four measurements.

Comment: I think so too but if i upload a texture via glTexImage2D width*height*bitDepth memory is allocated "by my" application which is not true.

Comment: If you upload data to the GPU, then this might be done asynchronous. In this case, the driver will have to copy the data from the pointer you passed to some temporary memory. Maybe this is what you seeing.

Comment: There's a good article here about how to measure memory usage.  As you've discovered, it's harder than you think.  http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2016/01/05/windows-process-memory-usage-demystified/